# How to know which program has just played sound?

Tags: macos, audio, mac

At times, my computer suddenly played some annoying short sound (sounds like *darrrt*, seems not from the system), and it's so short that I have no idea where it comes from (and cannot capture it).

Is there any ways to find which program/process did that? (I really want to kill it!)

<sup>I am using OS X Mavericks.</sup>

Comment: Short buzzer sound is used by the calendar notifications in most cases. Observe whether a reminder appears on top right of the screen or in the notification center.

Comment: [`dtrace`](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/10/10/top-10-dtrace-scripts-for-mac-os-x/) might be able to probe the information. A quick look over the in built scripts doesn't seem to provide anything to probe specific devices though so probably needs a custom script

Comment: Thanks for coming back with an answer, but can you please add it as an answer below (and accept it) instead of modifying the question?

Comment: @patrix Thanks for your comment. I just followed your advice.

Comment: It's crazy that MacOS lacks this feature. Windows had it for so long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all answers! The problem was solved, it was turned out to be caused by a Safari plug-in( notifier of Gmail ).
Method: inspiration(sorry guys I just found it out by realizing I installed a weird plugin... really hard to explain how the idea came to my mind...).

Comment: It would probably help others if you explained how you figured out the cause (i.e., what method you used to identify which app was responsible).  That might help others in the same situation, even if they don't have the same Safari plug-in.

Answer (score 26):

Here is what I did to find a pesky application playing a system file. Go to System Preferences -> Sound -> Sound Effects. Toggle through the effects and make note of the sound that your mystery application is playing. When you find it go to the terminal and type:

```
sudo fs_usage | grep "aiff"
```

Enter in the system password if asked.

Wait for the sound to get played again and then look at the terminal output. Look for the name of the sound file you noted in the sound effects and look all the way to the right. On the right you should see the application that played the sound file. Now simply go to that application and tell it to disable playing the sound file if possible.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was busy trying to track down a periodic basso sound. I thought it was my email client or RocketChat but it turned out to be SpamSieve. It would have taken days or even weeks to find the guilty app without your suggestion. It's not necessary to pre-research the sound. Your terminal command shows all recent sounds, which unless a user is running lots of sound notifications, should be enough.

Comment: Working in Monterey 12.0, fyi.

Comment: This was super helpful!  Thank you, still works in monterey 12.2.1 .  Note that for sounds that aren't aiff files, you may need a different grep.  I had run `open file.m4a` and that command returned to the prompt but the file was playing in the background, and I had to grep for it by its extension instead:  `sudo fs_usage | grep "m4a"` - will be hard to guess the format if you don't know, but if like me you did...this is the way to find it!

Answer (score 10):

While it's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/748949/55075) to check that directly, here are some workarounds:

- If you're using Google Chrome (or similar web-browser), look for speaker icon next to tab or window (e.g. check in *Window* menu).
- If you're using Safari, you should see also speaker icon next to the tab which is playing.
- Some apps such as [SoundFlower](https://github.com/marivera/Soundflower) can provide extra kernel extension for pass-through audio, so then they can check which processes are accessing sound device.
- Double check *Notifications* in *System Preferences*, and either set *Do Not Disturb* or disable *Play sound for notifications* for the recent or all apps. See this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/83028/22781).
- Check for log entries, e.g. by the following command:

  ```
  log stream --level=debug
  ```
- Check for any file activity by `fs_usage` command, e.g.

  ```
  sudo fs_usage
  ```
- Using trial and error, pause and resume processes to find out about the process, e.g.

  ```
  ps d
  kill -STOP 1234 5678 # Stop processes via PID(s).
  kill -CONT 1234 5678 # Resume selected processes.
  ```

Comment: I actually had some odd thing happen. I think it was probably related to an embedded YT video on twitter. I closed chrome and it kept on playing for several minutes through "com.apple."

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like the iMessage logged in notification.

Try this command in terminal to verify:

```
afplay "/Applications/Messages.app/Contents/Resources/Logged In.aiff"
```

To turn if off you can turn off "Play sound effects" in the iMessage preferences.

Answer (score 6):

[SoundBunny](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/soundbunny.php) might be able to help with this. The primary purpose of the app is to let you control various apps' sound levels, but it also usually shows you what apps have *recently* made sounds, which might help.

You can download a free demo from their [website](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/soundbunny.php) and leave it running until you hear the noise again, then switch over to SoundBunny and see what it shows.

Comment: How does it show what apps have recently made sounds? From what I can tell it just shows an alphabetical list of the apps that are open. And the log doesn't show when sounds are played, just when apps start/end.

Comment: "THIS PRODUCT HAS BEEN DISCONTINUED AND NO LONGER AVAILABLE" =(

Comment: 7 years is a long time.

Comment: It appears that version 5 of SoundSource _might_ be able to do this:  https://weblog.rogueamoeba.com/2020/08/05/soundsource-5-is-sound-control-reimagined/

Answer (score 4):

In my case it turned out to be PowerChime, chiming over and over in the way it does when you plug in power because I was using a bad USB-C port.

The `fs_usage` suggestion made by others was key, but here's a more complete example. Building on the suggestions of others, I first opened a terminal and ran:

```
sudo fs_usage
```

This printed too much information, so I started to winnow it down. If I suspected a program had nothing to do with it, I hit control-C, hit the up arrow and edited my command line to use `grep -v` to filter out that program:

```
sudo fs_usage | grep -v zoom
```

But this added a lot of entries for `grep` itself, so I filtered that too:

```
sudo fs_usage | grep -v zoom | grep -v grep
```

Eventually I added about six different steps to this pipeline, at which point I could see that `PowerChime` kept popping up. That was my clue to think about my bad USB C port problem and realize I had the power cord plugged into it.

Answer (score 1):

[Boom 3D](https://www.globaldelight.com/storefs/upgrade-boom3d.php) can do this, and a lot more.

Install it, enable system-wide support in the main window of the app (it requires you to install another extension), then you can click on the tray icon:

[image]

Just click on the purple button near the top-right corner, and you will be shown a list of all the apps and their volume. Apps playing music will have a little green circle:

[image]

Comment: @Allan I know, but this is just sharing a program's name, the link is there only for convenience. And there is really not much to explain why it is the best, as it is not the best. Other answers are just as valid.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to explain *how* somebody could use this application to solve the problem described in the question? From looking at the feature description it's hard to see how this could work.

Comment: @patrix Done ;)

Comment: Downloaded the app. I found no place to check what the author of this post is saying

Answer (score 0):

Didn't know where the annoying sound from my computer was coming from luckily
i read somewhere that something can get stuck in the safari cahe… i cleared it and it worked for me below is how to do it.
command alt e is the quickest way …but if you want to be sure

Select the first item “Safari” in the main menu and from the drop-down the item “Preferences…”
A popup opens. Click on the tab “Advanced”.
Check the option “Show Develop menu in menu bar” at the bottom. Now you should see a new menu item in the main menu named “Develop”.
If you click on the menu item “Develop” you can select “Empty Caches” from the submenu items.
Reload the site.