# intermittent alert sound tritone playing

Tags: alert

running HighSierra and hearing intermittent tritone sounds. I noticed that the sound happened at the same time as the previous day.

There are no user applications/scripts open when this happens, even after rebooting.

I would like to know if there is a way to find out where this alert sound is coming from and how to disable it.

EDIT - the sound seems to happen at the same time every day. At first it was at 9:30 pm, now it is happening at 3:30 pm daily.

Comment: You'll need to provide us more details than this, what applications do you have open at the time of it happening? Do you have any Automator scripts/Apple Scripts set to run?

Comment: question updated

Comment: @Allan I tried this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/323092/176218 and the output of the terminal was null when the sound played. The sound only plays once a day, so I will have to wait 24 hours before trying again.  This is really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Since the notifications are happening at a specific time, open up "Console" (the application) at 3:29PM. Let it sit for a minute until you hear the sound, then click the `Activities` button to see if there's anything there regarding a system sound playing. If you can't find it there, go back and check the rest of the message.

Then identify the process and reinstall the application that is triggering it or handle it in whatever way seems fit.

[image]

Click this `activities` button inside of your console window to access the
[image]

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include where someone might find activities tab?

Comment: thanks for the photo, but I still have no clue where this is located XD

Comment: There you go, good luck!

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Console is an application in the Utlities folder which is inside the Applications folder. If you don't know where your applications folder is, use the "Go" menu on the Finder toolbar.

Comment: I cant press the`activities` button as it is greyed out. I did open the log file and the only thing I see that sticks out is "Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook" but this seems to happen all day, not just at 3:30