# How to fix periodic ding sound on Mac Book

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

An irritating ding sound keeps playing which is a kind of notification or alert with out any visual guidance to figure whats going wrong. 
(The situation is almost like a pilot of Boeing 747 Max who doesn't know how to turn off anti stall system. :o) )

I found some solutions mentioned [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82987/what-is-causing-this-sound-on-my-mac#) However none worked for me.

Anyone has a clue?

Comment: Hi Sasikanth, is the sound problem you are talking of the same as in the linked question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is causing this sound on my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82987/what-is-causing-this-sound-on-my-mac)

Answer (score 2):

After a trial and error I found Chrome is causing the irritating ding notification.